# Looking for a PHP or MySQL equivalent for MariaDB's COLUMN_ADD function

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I think that the title is pretty explanatory, but just to be clear, I am migrating from MariaDB to Mysql and I am trying to find a solution to rewrite this query, to work on MySQL.

```
UPDATE `categories` SET attrib=COLUMN_ADD(attrib, '2','48'), updated=NOW() WHERE name = 'category_name'
```

I've tried like this:

```
UPDATE `categories` SET attrib=CONCAT(attrib, '2','48'), updated=NOW() WHERE name = 'category_name'
```

But it just concatenates the values 2 and 48 into 248, and I need the actual value to be a json string and each time I run the query, it should push new data into that json string.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I fixed it using [JSON_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) instead of `COLUMN_ADD`

```
UPDATE `categories` SET attrib=JSON_SET(attrib, '$."2"', "48"), updated=NOW() WHERE name = 'category_name'
```